# A flammable gas in a energized conductive container

Tags: electric-current

I place a flammable gas (natural gas) inside a metal container and energize the container (apply AC current).  Do I have any concerns at this point.  I understand for combustion to occur I have to have oxygen available.  I also know that some gasses combust underwater (torch welding).  I assume it's because oxygen is applied.

To extend my example, would there be any concerns from this community with someone using a natural gas pipe in their home as a ground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The far I know is "Safety first!"
Since you're playing with fire, then even if the risk level were 0, there should be no need to try.

Regarding theoretical analysis, not only oxygen to be mixed with gas, but also at some limits known as flammability limits or explosive limits. Explosion or firing takes place if the oxygen contents were between the lower and upper flammability limits (LEL/UEL).

Heat as a source should also reach the fire point (specific temperature at which the mixture continues burning).

In my opinion, apart from all precautions, never ever think about it!

Answer (score -1):

The Natural gas flammability limit is 4% to 17% , if there is little to no oxygen it will not result in a flame.

Comment: 4% to 17% of what? Is that the percentage of oxygen present in natural gas?